# Angular 2: Existing solution for discussion implementations

Tags: angular

I have Angular 2 app. I would like to impl a discussion. Is there any **already existing solution**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several npm packages for adding components such as Disqus:

[NG2-Awesome-Disqus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-awesome-disqus)

[NG2-Disqus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-disqus)

[Angular2-disqus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-disqus)

I haven't used any of these, but it sounds like what you are looking for.